# CDF of the function of a random variable

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

I haven't been able to find useful information on this. I was just wondering what would be the distribution of a function of a random variable.

For example, what would be the distribution of the $c\, X^{(1/k)}$ where $c$ is a constant and $X$ is $\sim\text{exp}(1)$?

Thank You

Comment: This looks like routine bookwork. Is this for some class?

Comment: Or are you interested in the general approach to such problems?

Comment: I have given one simple approach that works on the example problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the cdf of invertible transformations of r.v.s using elementary methods:

Assume for the moment that $g$ is a monotonic increasing transformation (monotonic decreasing can be handled similarly if you take care about the direction of the inequality; non-invertible transformations need to be dealt with more carefully, generally by splitting the transformation up into invertible sections)

Let $Y=g(X)$

$F_Y(y)= P(Y\leq y) = P(g(X)\leq y) = P(X\leq g^{-1}(y)) = F_X( g^{-1}(y))$

If you also need the density, you can take the derivative.

If you follow this through on your example, you get a well known cdf and density

There's also a formula for calculating the density more directly (which you can derive from the above argument), but you don't really need it here.