# How to add and multiply distributions?

Tags: self-study, distributions, definition, transform

I saw in a statistics book a problem.

Let $X$ be a distribution that gets $1$ for probability $0.4$ and $2$ for probability $0.6$. Compute the mean and variances of $Y=3X-2$ and $Y=3X^2-2$. I found formulas and solved the problem. But how one defines the distributions $3X-2$ and $3X^2-2$? Because I found that $3\cdot 0.4-2+4\cdot 0.6-2=1.2-2+2.4-2=-0.6\ne 1$.

I have read mathematics so I'm not afraid to see a formal definition of the distribution or how to transform them.

Comment: Welcome to the site! In the future, please add the self-study tag for this type of question. (I did it for this one.)

Comment: Your description of $X$ is that of a *random variable* rather than a distribution.  Our posts about random variables may help you understand better what expressions like $3X-2$ and $3X^2-2$ mean.  Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50 and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95993.  The question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140060/cdf-of-the-function-of-a-random-variable is a generalized version of yours, couched in terms of distribution functions (CDFs).

Comment: The random variable X is a discrete random variable. X has mean 0.4 + 1.2 =1.6 and its variance is 0.4 (1 -1.6)$^2$+0.6 (2-1.6)$^2$=0.144+0.96=0.24.  In the first case Y is  linear function of X so E(Y)=3 E(X)-2. Var(Y)=9 Var(X).

Comment: The second case is more complicated.  But another way to get the moments of Y would be first determine the distribution of Y and directly calculate its mean and variance in the same way I did for X. In your question it is not clear what you are computing when you say -0.6 is not equal to 1.